# What is CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making Facebook login with Codeigniter.
I have this error:

*A PHP Error was encountered*

*Severity: Notice*

*Message: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE - assumed 'CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE'*

*Filename: libraries/base_facebook.php*

*Line Number: 1012*

I've read about it on StackOverflow. I have to update CURL, but how do I do that?
My website is on free web hosting server (http://www.000webhost.com)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What @TerryHarvey said. It's basically impossible for you to update cURL yourself.

Comment: @slugonamission I wasn't answering the question, otherwise I would have posted an answer. I was merely making a comment on his choice of hosting ;)

Comment: @TerryHarvey - whoops, there should have been a "said" after your name. My mind stopped working properly about an hour ago :P

Comment: @slugonamission ah, apologies!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE` is a constant defining one of cURL options that can be set with [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

To quote the manual, it:

> Allows an application to select what kind of IP addresses to use when
>   resolving host names. This is only interesting when using host names
>   that resolve addresses using more than one version of IP, possible
>   values are CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4,
>   CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6, by default CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER.

This functionality is available since cURL 7.10.8 and the constant itself is defined in PHP 5.3 and newer.

I don't know how cURL < 7.10.8 resolves addresses with more than one IP by default, but if you're still on PHP 5.2 and can't upgrade, commenting out the line that triggers the notice *shouldn't* break anything.