# Notice: Use of undefined constant CURL_IPRESOLVE - assumed 'CURL_IPRESOLVE'

Tags: php, curl, ipv6, ipv4

I have 2 IP address on my dedicated server

> 1. ipv4
> 2. ipv6

i m trying to use ipv6 on CURL, below are code using on curl.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURL_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

or

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4, true);
```

but i got below error

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURL_IPRESOLVE - assumed 'CURL_IPRESOLVE' in /home/admin....... line 14
```

Comment: CURL**OPT**_IPRESOLVE

Answer (score 3):

you have to use `CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER` for both IP versions

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER);
```

More information refere this [DOC](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE.html)

Comment: i want to use ipv4 or ipv6 only

Comment: yes, its work there is no other ip verisons exists in internet protocalls

Comment: haresh @ are you from gujrat ?

Comment: yes.. Ahmedabad,if you like it mark as correct and up vote :)

Comment: not working for me... Curl use only IPV6 ... i want use IPV4

Comment: check this post also... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818002/what-is-curlopt-ipresolve

Comment: `CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER` is the default option, it should be useless to set it

Comment: @CalEliacheff, I am agree with you... :)

Comment: The problem is, you typed `CURL_IPRESOLVE` and the correct one is `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE`.

Answer (score 1):

To use specifically IPv4, use

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);`

Official doc here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Please double check it, in your example you wrote `CURL_IPRESOLVE` instead of `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE`